# Apply mgsub function on whole data.frame in R

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I often work with tables full with **special characters** (f.e. á,ľ,š,č,ť,ž,ý,á,í,é,... etc.).
I found very useful function called `mgsub` which can do simultaneous multiple string replacement.
**I works well of vector, however I am struggling to apply which function to whole dataframe.**

Function `mgsub` work like this:

```
library(mgsub)
mgsub::mgsub("...A čo i tam dušu dáš v tom boji divokom: Mor ty len, a voľ nebyť, ako byť otrokom.",
             pattern = c(".","A","č","š","á",":",",","ľ","ť","M"," "),
         replacement = c("","a","c","s","a","","","","t","m",""), fixed = TRUE)
[1] "acoitamdusudasvtombojidivokommortylenavonebytakobytotrokom"
```

But how to apply this function to whole data.frame? For example on this data.frame...

```
my.df <- data.frame(v1 = c("...A čo i tam dušu","dáš v tom boji"),
                    v2 = c("divokom:","Mor ty len,"),
                    v3 = c("a voľ nebyť,","ako byť otrokom."))

                  v1          v2               v3
1 ...A čo i tam dušu    divokom:     a voľ nebyť,
2     dáš v tom boji Mor ty len, ako byť otrokom.
```

I tried to aplly lapply. but it gives only errors...

```
data.frame(lapply(my.df, mgsub::mgsub,
                  pattern = c(".","A","č","š","á",":",",","ľ","ť","M"," "),
                  replacement = c("","a","c","s","a","","","","t","m",""), fixed = TRUE))
Error in nchar(string) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: For the special characters, there is also a nice function in `stringi` library called `stri_trans_general()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the columns are `factor` and `mgsub` requires a `character` input.  According to `?mgsub`

> string - a character vector where replacements are sought

---

Either convert all the columns to `character` class

```
my.df[] <- lapply(my.df, as.character)
```

Or use `type.convert`

```
my.df <- type.convert(my.df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Or use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the `data.frame` as the default option in `data.frame` is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`

```
my.df <- data.frame(v1 = c("...A čo i tam dušu","dáš v tom boji"),
                    v2 = c("divokom:","Mor ty len,"),
                    v3 = c("a voľ nebyť,","ako byť otrokom."), 
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```